# The feeling of a storm approaching

Tags: single-word-requests

In my current situation I can feel the probably well known sensation that a thunderstorm is approaching. When everything goes dark and cold and you simply just *feel* that a storm is coming. Having been on the dictionary of obscure sorrows I'm pretty sure there is a word for this, but I simply cannot find it.

Is there a single word for the feeling that a (thunder)storm is approaching? If not, is there any better way to express this feeling than simply saying "I feel a storm approaching"?

Edit: the feeling I am describing isn't *negative* but rather a feeling of excitement or tension

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a sense of **heightened anticipation** for any stimulus expected anxiously, whether real or imagined.

Definition of anticipation, 
[Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anticipation), 12th Ed:][1](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anticipation)

> 1. the act of anticipating; expectation, premonition, or foresight

Comment: Its less of a feeling of impending doom but rather a tingling sensation, more like excitement or tension, definitely not anxiety though

Answer (score 0):

I have a **premonition**, or a feeling of **foreboding**

> - [**premonition**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/premonition)  (noun) - "a presentiment of the future, a foreboding, a warning in advance"
> - [**foreboding**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/foreboding) noun -  "a sense of impending evil or misfortune"

Edit: The OP says the word or phrase shouldn't have a negative connotation. I therefore suggest **"a feeling of apprehension"**

Comment: I should have probably mentioned its not a negative feeling, its rather a feeling of excitement

Comment: @7H3_H4CK3R   "an approaching thunderstorm" sounds pretty negative to me.

Comment: to those who dislike thunderstorms that is. I identify as a ceraunophile, a person who loves lightning and thunder

Comment: This is far too general; the general question (a feeling that **something** bad is about to happen) would be a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

I do not really know if this will help you. From a scientific perspective you may want to look up or google "infrasound"

Infrasound is what is thought to be heard by many animals, that alerts them to storms.

Other words that came to mind - goosebumps, premonition, hair rising on the back your neck.  Some type of sixth sense or extrasensory "feeling"

Comment: I was more trying to describe the feeling that it causes, but nonetheless its interesting to know that infrasound is the cause of this.